# How to find out if a cell is within a specific range of rows in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, range, google-sheets-formula, cell

I am trying to figure out if a cell in Google Sheets is between a specified range of rows in the sheet. (Example: if cell A3 is within the range of rows 2-35, then do X task, else do Y task). Is there any way to do this using any built-in functions in Google Sheets, or if anyone can do a step by step on how to use Google Script to do the same task?

I have tried `=If(and($A3>=$A$2:$Z$35, $A3<=$A$36:$Z$1000)`, X task, Y task) but it won't work. Is there a built-in function that does this task?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SUhA7IQXJff1eKBr4KMX9SJO8Ms1JOzUbVX1ta9hcqk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: answer updated...

Comment: Based on the spreadsheet you shared and the explanation you provided, it's not clear for me what you are trying to do. Can you show what the desired output is?

Answer (score 2):

it would be like this:

```
=IF(MATCH(A3, C3:C35, 0), "x", "y")
```

---

### update:

```
=QUERY(SORT(B1:G, 4, 0), 
 "select 'Master',Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6 
  limit 10
  label 'Master''Rank'", 1)
```

[image]